# The script is still being executed even after Destroy() was called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, callback, game-development, lifecycle

In the following code, when the player health reach 0 the game object is destroyed by using Destroy() method. But when the game play, the print() statement sometimes produced -1. I tested several times but it never show -2. It means the script is still being executed 1 time even after calling Destroy() method. I also tested with enabled flag by setting false and it has the same result. Destroying game object or Disabling/Enabling script doesn't effect immediately?

```
private void CheckDamageCollision(Collision2D other)
{
    if (!other.gameObject.CompareTag(Constants.TAG_ENEMY) && !other.gameObject.CompareTag(Constants.TAG_OBSTACLE) && !other.gameObject.CompareTag(Constants.TAG_ENEMY_WEAPON)) return;
    if (justDamage) return;
    --health;
    PlayerDamage?.Invoke(health);
    if (health < 1)
    {
        print("Health : " + health);
        PlayerDead?.Invoke();
        IgnoreLayerMatrix(false);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }
    StartCoroutine(WaitNextDamageCollide());
}
```

The code above is used only inside the CollisionEnter callback.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    CheckDamageCollision(other);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided seems ok. However, it's hard to tell for certain because I can't see what's inside functions such as `PlayerDamage?.Invoke(health);`

If this happens only sometimes, it could be because `OnCollisionEnter2D` occurs more than once per frame and `Destroy()` only gets invoked after the end of that frame in the *decommissioning* phase:

> "The physics cycle may happen more than once per frame if the fixed time step is less than the actual frame update time" - *https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html*

To avoid this, you could introduce a flag `isDamagedThisFrame` and check if the player is not being damaged, then invoke all of your damage stuff, and set `isDamagedThisFrame` to `true`. Set the flag back to `false` at the end of the frame, when all physics updates have finished.

```cs
private bool isDamagedThisFrame = false;

private void CheckDamageCollision(Collision2D other)
{
    if (!other.gameObject.CompareTag(Constants.TAG_ENEMY) && !other.gameObject.CompareTag(Constants.TAG_OBSTACLE) && !other.gameObject.CompareTag(Constants.TAG_ENEMY_WEAPON)) return;
    if (justDamage) return;

    if (isDamagedThisFrame) return;
    isDamagedThisFrame = true;

    --health;
    PlayerDamage?.Invoke(health);
    if (health < 1)
    {
        print("Health : " + health);
        PlayerDead?.Invoke();
        IgnoreLayerMatrix(false);
        Destroy(gameObject);
        return;
    }
    StartCoroutine(WaitNextDamageCollide());
}
```

in your `WaitNextDamageCollide()` you can `yield WaitForEndOfFrame`

```cs
IEnumerator WaitNextDamageCollide() {
   // ... your code
   yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
   isDamagedThisFrame = false;
}
```

Comment: No changes even if I don't use code like Event invocation. It seems because of Unity physics life cycle. But AFAIK physics related callbacks are called more than once when the actual frame update is less than physics update. When I check the stats in Unity editor, fps is around 120 and physics timestamp is 0.02s. So, actual frame update is more than physics update.

Answer (score 0):

Destroy is called at the end of the frame. You can use [destroy immediate function](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html) but it has some performance overhead. If it's a small game then go ahead and use it. Otherwise you can set the collider to disabled on collision, so that the next OnCollisionEnter2D is not called and the script will be destroyed by end of the frame.

Comment: Using `DestroyImmediate` is not recommended. 

This function should only be used when writing editor code since the delayed destruction will never be invoked in edit mode. In game code you should use `Object.Destroy` instead.